# I want to display Date and Time in label when user selects particular Date and Time in DatePicker control in monotouch for ios using objective-c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am new to ios apps, I tried one sample example for `DatePicker` control but the problem is, I am getting only current Date and Time.

I have added `DatePicker` control and `label` to view in Xcode and I added this

```
lblDtp.Text = dtp.Date.ToString ();
```

in `ViewDidLoad ()` its working fine and showing current date and time but I like to display Date and Time in label when user selects particular Date and Time in `DatePicker` control.Can you please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
NSDate *appDate = [datePicker date];
NSDateFormatter *form = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[form setDateFormat:@"YYYYMMddHHmmss"];
NSString *str = [form stringFromDate:appDate];
lblDtp.Text = str;
```

`datePicker` is your DatePicker